# Is there a map of packages across the different package management systems?

Tags: package, yum, apt-get, package-managers

I have amassed a small collection of *nix boxes (Fedora, Ubuntu, CentOS and Puppy) and there are a couple of projects I'm considering that I need to install additional libraries. Specifically, this OpenCV stuff:
http://www.samontab.com/web/2011/06/installing-opencv-2-2-in-ubuntu-11-04/

However, his instructions are for Ubuntu, using apt-get, and I want to do the same on CentOS which uses "yum". So is there some place that maps packages across package managers? I tried this on Fedora:

```
sudo yum install build-essential libgtk2.0-dev libjpeg62-dev libtiff4-dev libjasper-dev libopenexr-dev cmake python-dev python-numpy libtbb-dev libeigen2-dev yasm libfaac-dev libopencore-amrnb-dev libopencore-amrwb-dev libtheora-dev libvorbis-dev libxvidcore-dev
```

There are a few hits, but a lot of "No package xxxx available". So, I'm hoping there is a place that shows what the package names are in what package manager.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is OS related and not a programming question as defined in the site guidelines. It is better suited for [unix.se] or [su].

Comment: Damn, Sorry. I'll post there. Thanks!

Comment: Posted here in case anyone else gets lost:

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/107246/is-there-a-map-of-package-names-across-the-different-package-management-systems